# Call method from string inside class?

Tags: python, string, methods, getattr

I am trying to call fucntions using string value. Here is a simple example of my problem. How to call `method(line)` properly? I tried different solutions and got success only with `@staticmethod` but this is not what I want.

```
class A():

    def prime(self, key):
        line = 'Good'
        method = getattr(A, key)
        method(line)

    def add1(self, string):
        print string + ' day!'

    def add2(self, string):
        print string + ' evening!'



def main():
    test = A()
    test.prime('add1')
    test.prime('add2')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: why do you want it to be a string when you can just call it normally

Comment: because this is simple example of my problem.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to pass a string rather than a reference to the method itself? test.prime(A.add1), then def prime(self, method): method(self, "Good")`

Comment: Yes, because user has an access to parameters and it is easier to make inputs as simple strings. I hope, now it's more clear

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass `self` to `getattr` instead of the class name:

```
method = getattr(self, key)
method(line)
```

---

Also, if this is Python 2, you should inherit from `object` in most cases, to use [new-style classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python):

```
class A(object):
```

Comment: @Gatto you're welcome :-). If this answer solves your problem, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`operator.methodcaller`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller):

```
def prime(self, key):
    operator.methodcaller(key, "Good")(self)
```